# mod_cloudflare & Bandwidth , Large traffic

Tags: apache, caching, server, traffic, cloudflare

I installed mod_cloudflare on my servers 
my server for files downloads 
Example: 
server01.domain.com 
server02.domain.com 
These servers to download files with direct links 
Example: server01.domain.com/example.zip 
The mod work fine mod_cloudflare 
But the problem: 
If I enable "Traffic will be accelerated by CloudFlare" "orange clouds" on my subdomain server01.domain.com , files server 
Amount of data traffic is increase very large passage, Why? 
Amount outgoing bandwidth from the server very high !! 
And i added the subdomain in page rule 
server01.domain.com/ 
Cache level: Bypass cache or cache everything or any option 
Did not succeed !!
see.. 
http://s02.arab.sh/i/00021/nviwqwxjax72.png 
http://s02.arab.sh/i/00021/omz3nl1ne3bz.png 
How I can fix this ? To back the bandwidth normal with enable "Traffic will be accelerated by CloudFlare" 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We (CloudFlare) wouldn't be doing anything that would send additional traffic or bandwidth to your site (bandwidth usage should be quite the opposite). mod_cloudflare also really doesn't add any overhead to your site, since the only thing it is doing is returning the original visitor IP (ours show without it), so what you're reporting seems strange.

Note: PageRules do not bypass our proxy.